# Leaflet map is not with full height size in Vuetify container on mobile

Tags: vue.js, mobile, vuejs2, leaflet, vuetify.js

I added Leaflet map inside Vuetify container (fluid) with 'app-bar' - it is working fine on desktop (or in Device toolbar of Developer console) but on mobile map zoom controls located under the navbar panel (when we click on zoom control buttons).

[image]

What could be the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Proposed workaround to this Chrome specific behavior is to prevent Leaflet from focusing the map:

```
L.Control.include({
  _refocusOnMap: L.Util.falseFn
});
```

Source: [How to prevent Leaflet map resizing on zoom in Vue/Vuetify app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441260/how-to-prevent-leaflet-map-resizing-on-zoom-in-vue-vuetify-app)